Hotswap Smart Array P410i controller, 8 ST9300653SS disks
I need to replace a failed disk in an HP ProLiant DL380P Gen6, Smart Array P410i controller, with eight ST9300653SS disks 300GB 15K.
I ordered the same disk. I found information that the controller supports hotplug, but I did not understand whether this function will work with these disks? I plan to do it this way:

hpssacli ctrl slot=0 pd 1I:1:4 modify led=on
Physically replace the disk
hpssacli ctrl slot=0 pd 1I:1:4 replace
Check the array recovery status:
hpssacli ctrl slot=0 ld 1 show rebuild

Tell me, or correct me, how to do it better? thanks.

if its dead, it's dead. unplug and replug the new device. if its get alive then it's fine. however this question is offtopic due gen 6 is EOL.

hotplug, but I did not understand whether this function will work with these disks? the disk is mounted in a caddy with a button and pull lever on the front. If the replacement disk does not have this, it will not work.

The hotplug is function of the controller, not of the disks. If controller supports it, it will work with any disks supported by the controller.
Normally, for the list of supported disks, you can refer to the hardware compatibility list on the HP website; it's often given to specific server version. But since your server is gen 6, it is EOL (end of life) and out of support, which means, you probably won't find that information on the web site anymore. It's recommended to replace the server, not disks.
With disks that should be compatible (that is, any SATA or SAS devices), but not listed, YMMV. You can try to screw the failed disk out of the caddy and screw the new disk in, then plug it in. Most likely it'll work, but the controller will complain that you have an unsupported disk, and it will always be in a "warning" state on that grounds. Since your server is out of support anyway, this probably wouldn't make things any worse than they are now.
Your replacement procedure is correct, although modern versions of this software are called simply ssacli, not hpssacli (and, for completeness, not hpacucli, which is the ancient name of the same program).

Thank you Nikita, HP included a list of specific drives that (not)support hotplug in the manual. This is what misled me https://community.hpe.com/hpeb/attachments/hpeb/itrc-264/141905/1/HP%20Smart%20Array%20P410%20Controller.pdf

I'm inclined to think this is one of HP's usual bullshits they always do to pull more money out of their loyal customers. I am sure these are exactly the same drives as "hot plug" ones up there, just with one bit flipped in firmware. // The drive can not possibly distinguish the genuine machine start from the hot plug event. Also, in servers with many drives they are powered on sequentially, to conserve PSU power, a so called staggered spin-up, so some of them have to start later; it's like they're always "hot plugged". And SAS/SATA connectors are physically designed for hot plug.
